# Error trying to copy data from Azure SQL database to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I have created a pipeline in Azure data factory (V1). I have a copy pipeline, that has an AzureSqlTable data set on input and AzureBlob data set as output. The AzureSqlTable data set that I use as input, is created as output of another pipeline. In this pipeline I launch a procedure that copies one table entry to blob csv file.
I get the following error when launching pipeline:

> Copy activity encountered a user error: ErrorCode=UserErrorTabularCopyBehaviorNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=CopyBehavior property is not supported if the source is tabular data source.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'.
>
> How can I solve this?

Comment: Try creating a custom activity instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo the problem is that with our subscription we have no rights to create a batch service, so custom activity is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, actually, if we don't use this awful "Copy data (PREVIEW)" action and we actually add an activity to existing pipeline and not a new pipeline - everything works. So the solution is to add a copy activity manually into an existing pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error information, it indicateds that it is not supported action for Azure data factory, but if use Azure sql table as input and Azure blob data as output it should be [supported by Azure data factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-data-movement-activities#supported-data-stores-and-formats).

I also do a demo test it with Azure portal. You also could follow the detail steps to do that.

1.Click the copy data from Azure portal.

[image]

2.Set copy properties.

[image]

3.Select the source

[image]

[image]

4.Select the destination data store

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

5.Complete the deployment

[image]

6.Check the result from azure and storage.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

If we want to use the existing dataset we could choose [From Existing Conections], for more information please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

**Update2:**

For Data Factory(v1) copy activity settings it just supports to use existing Azure blob storage/Azure Data Lake Store Dataset. More detail information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-tool#use-the-copy-data-tool-to-create-a-pipeline).

[image]

If using Data Factory(V2) is acceptable, we could using existing azure sql dataset.

[image]

Comment: If I do like this it works, however it creates a new input data set and I need to reuse the one that already exists, and when we use copy data (preview) it doesn't offer a possibility to use an existing data set as an input set.

Comment: @KateHamster If we want to use the existing dataset we could choose  **[From Existing Conections]**, I also updated the answer, for more details please refer to the updated answer.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it uses only an existing linked service, but it creates a new input dataset.

Comment: For Data Factory(v1) copy activity settings it just supports to use existing Azure blob storage/Azure Data Lake Store Dataset,If using Data Factory(V2) is acceptable, we could using existing azure sql dataset.